# How does 'Stock stock = new Stock("HR.S")' lead to an output?

Tags: java

I'm extremely new to Java, and I'm trying to understand why an output of the main method of the Magic class for this code is "TT". Our professor said we don't have to understand the meaning of this method, but just answer the output.

The code is this.

```
public class Magic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String MSG = "Good Restaurant Seattle";
        Stock stock = new Stock("HR.S");
        double price = stock.getPrice();
        int cent = (int) Math.rint(price);
        System.out.println(MSG.substring(cent, cent+2).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

I understand where it took the letters from and how all variables such as cent and price are connected, but I don't understand what "HR.S" is and how it's connected to the output.

Comment: `"HR.S"` is a String (text enclosed by brackets (")) and to understand why it is used, you need to go to the `Stock` class and look at the constructor. The constructor is a method that has the same name as the class itself. Nevertheless, this is not a stack overflow question. If you want to learn about java, then I recommend the book **Java: The complete reference [9th edition]** and can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Shailendra-Java/Library/raw/master/Java%20-%20The%20Complete%20Reference%2C%209th%20Edition%20-%20Herbert%20Schildt.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `MSG.substring(cent, cent+2).toUpperCase()` to return `TT`, the value of `cent` has to be 20.

```
....:....1....:....2...
Good Restaurant Seattle
                   ^^
```

In order for `cent` to be 20, the value of `price` must be `19.5 <= price <= 20.5`.

Which means that `stock.getPrice()` returned a value between 19.5 and 20.5 (inclusive).

Not knowing what class `Stock` does, we cannot say how it figured out that input `"HR.S"` should have such a price.